# FIle in the same Package is not Found

Tags: java, package, classpath

I am using spring framework.
I have an interface And a class In the same package.
My interface is

```
package soundsystem;

public interface CompactDisc{
    void play();
}
```

My class is

```
package soundsystem;
import org.springframework.stereotype.*;

@Component
public class Sgtpeppers implements CompactDisc{
    private String title = "A Movie";
    private String artist = "The Movie is Being Played";

    public void play(){
        System.out.println("The CD is Played \n"+title+"\n"+artist);
    }
}
```

On Compilation it gives me this error

```
Sgtpeppers.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
public class Sgtpeppers implements CompactDisc{
                                   ^
symbol: class CompactDisc
1 error
```

The Interface is Compiled First and the .class file is also stored the soundsystem package.

I Think there is something wrong with the javac Command.
The command i used is

```
javac -d . -cp "spring-framework-5.0.1.RELEASE/libs/*" Sgtpeppers.java
```

Is this because i changed the classpath?

Comment: You only put the spring jars in the classpath. Your class is not in any of those jar files. So javac can't find it. You also don't seem to respect the package hierarchy in your folders. This is Java 101. I think it's way too early for you to use Spring. Learn the basics first. What is a package, what is the classpath, how to lay out a project, how to use a build tool like Maven or gradle.

Comment: Can you tell me some good resources for learning what you just told.

Comment: The Java tutorial is usually a good resource. An introductory Java book should also teach all that stuff, except maybe the build tools. Gradle has a very good documentation.

Comment: Ok i will go through....And Thank you....!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) As a general rule, to compile classes, don't perform the task from the directory of a specific package.
Instead, use the root of the application source code as base to run the `javac`/`java` command.

By following this simple rule :

2)To compile all classes located in a same package, just specify the package as "source files" :

> javac soundsystem/*.java

3)To compile a specific class depending on another compiled class of your source code (in the same package or not), **you don't need to specify `"."` (that represents the current directory) in the classpath as it is the default value**.

[Java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html) states indeed that :

> The default class path is the current directory. Setting the CLASSPATH
>   variable or using the -classpath command-line option overrides that
>   default, so if you want to include the current directory in the search
>   path, then you must include a dot (.) in the new settings.

But if you explicitly set the classpath with another value, the default value is not more used.
And here you did it :

> javac -d . -cp "spring-framework-5.0.1.RELEASE/libs/*" Sgtpeppers.java

So you should add explicitly "." in the classpath too.

From the source code root, it would give on Windows :

> javac -d . -cp ".;spring-framework-5.0.1.RELEASE/libs/*" 
>   soundsystem/Sgtpeppers.java

For Unix, separator char is `:`, so it would give :

> javac -d . -cp ".:spring-framework-5.0.1.RELEASE/libs/*" 
>   soundsystem/Sgtpeppers.java

Comment: wow...It worked..! But i still did not Understand why should .: be used?

Comment: Because "." that represents the current directory is the default value  but if you set the CP, this default value is not more used any longer. I updated to stress on.